# How to upload Image Files using GoldRaccoon Library?

Tags: ios, xcode

In my iOS project created in xCode 6 I've integrated GoldRaccoon Library for FTP. I am able to send files if I am giving the upload file extension as '.txt'. But in my application I need to transfer images and videos. When i tried to transfer a '.png' file, I am getting error. How can I transfer these files.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked example here? https://github.com/albertodebortoli/GoldRaccoon.

Comment: See https://github.com/albertodebortoli/GoldRaccoon/issues/26#issuecomment-81516842

Answer (score 0):

As mention in issues of gold recon liabrary

[**GoldRaccoon Library issues**](https://github.com/albertodebortoli/GoldRaccoon/issues/26#issuecomment-81516842)

> Try to Just delete this line from openWrite method in GRStreamInfo.m
>   class
>
> ```
> CFWriteStreamSetProperty(writeStreamRef, kCFStreamPropertyFTPAttemptPersistentConnection, kCFBooleanFalse);
> ```

and try again.